# jQM Theme does not work properly on front page

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I've started to use Drupal recently, and installed the jQuery Mobile module and the jQM Theme in order to make a Mobile site / Web app.

I'm having some troubles getting it to work properly.

The thing is, that when I go to my sites front page, I get this view:

[image: screenshot]

However, if I click on, let's say 'Store Locator', I get this view:

[image: screenshot]

So my problem is, that it seems like the jQuery Mobile stuff (js or css) does not load correctly on the front page.

If I inspect the page, it seems to be the right template, but somehow the js og css isn't loaded correctly.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: in which browser have you tested it? (e.g. in which browser have you made the screenshots above?)

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the CSS/JS via your themes .info file? If so, the CSS/JS should be included in the order specified there. The only other thing you should check is that if you have a page override for the homepage (page-front.tpl.php) and verify you have the correct JS/CSS in place in there as well. 
Good luck

Comment: Hmm.. I quite new to all this, so I have to get my head around all the .info .module files and structures.. But the funny thing is, that the frontpage somehow loads some of the styling, cuz if I disables styles, it looks completely different.. So it's kinda weird..